# Can't seem to see local network on Wine

Tags: ubuntu, local-area-network, ethernet, wine

I'm trying to use Wine on Ubuntu to use a proprietary Windows program that looks for a proprietary device on the local network. I don't know where it's looking, which protocol, port or IP address it's using. That information is sealed. I only know it uses the Ethernet port.

It can't find the device in Wine. It can on Windows. It does not use any device drivers. All communication is done over Ethernet.

I tried poking around to see what could be going wrong. I tried several Windows LAN viewers and scanners on Wine, but none of them found any computers. So now I'm wondering: can Wine actually scan the local area network and find computers (or computer-like devices) on it? If so, how do I enable that ability?

My **Wine version** is **1.6.2** and I'm running it in a **32 bit prefix** on a **64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty** machine.

Comment: Is there really no other information you can provide about this program, the device it's looking for, or the intended network connection?

Comment: Fiddler is unable to discern the port / network traffic ?

Comment: I can tell you what type a device it is. It's a camera powered by POE (power over Ethernet). How it works is completely proprietary. It comes with proprietary Windows "drivers" that are really just an executable. The whole thing is sealed beyond that. Running the Windows program should display the image filmed by the camera. But it stops at "Looking for devices". Still, I also tried running programs called "MyLanViewer" and "LAN Explorer" and neither saw a computer on the network. If I could get those working first, I'd be more confident about getting the camera working afterwards.

Comment: Wait, are you sure they implemented LAN support with Wine ? Last time I checked, it just wasn't available.